# No generator named 'netcore' could be found

Tags: thrift

```
mkdir example
cd example
touch shared.thrift 
touch tutorial.thrift
thrift -r --gen js:node tutorial.thrift
```

=> I get the following warning

> [WARNING:/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/cisco/cdt-hive/example/shared.thrift:34]
>   No generator named 'netcore' could be found!

netcore is referenced in the tutorial.thrift file:

```
namespace netcore tutorial
```

should I be concerned?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. ;-) Trunk or next release, and very early state, patches welcome. PS: The tuts on the web site are generated from the master source tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use master. `netcore` support is not released yet.